# Ngspice -Scale set

Tags: ngspice

I am trying to simulate an SRAM in Ngspice. I am writing data into a particular address from an input port and reading the same from an output port while performing transient analysis. The simulation takes a couple of hours and then asks for "Scale set". The Ngspice manual says scale set is the quantity that is shown on x-axis. I want time on the x-axis but do not know how to indicate.

Comment: It's difficult to know with the information you gave. Did you mean `setscale`? What other commands are you using? Can you make a small test netlist to show how you are using the commands? Can you reproduce these problems with this smaller test schematic?

Comment: yes it is setscale from what I saw in the manual. I did not initially mention that in the spice file, so Ngspice shows up with this query- "Scale set".

Comment: Control statements that I used:                                                                                 meas tran Vdout1_30 AVG v(dout1_30) FROM=0.0n TO=50.0n (more of this kind- all for output ports),
tran 10p 50n UIC,                                                                                                                        plot allv

Comment: Try different settings with the solver, also LT spice has a much better solver, you may want to try your circuit there